# Nested If Statement first -notlike condition

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use nested IF statements to check a AD-Computer Attribute and if it is not either VM or VeraCrypt, use Manage-BDE to check the Bitlocker status.

When I use just `Get-Adcomputer <name> -Properties extensionAttribute1 | select extensionAttribute1` it returns the expected result VM.

When I do

```
$Attribute = Get-Adcomputer <name> -Properties extensionAttribute1 | select extensionAttribute1
Write-Host $Attribute
```

I get `@{extensionAttribute1=VM}`

I have tried many using `-Notlike "*VM*` but this did not work.

Here is my code.

```
# -----------------------
# Define global variables
# -----------------------

$ScanCount = 0
$UnprotectedCount = 0
$Date = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$StartDate = Get-Date -Format HH:mm:ss
$ReportFile = "C:\BitLocker_Status\BitLocker_Status.csv"
$BackupFile = "C:\BitLocker_Status\BitLocker_Status_Backup$BackupCopy'_$Date.csv"
$OutputArray = @()
$BackupCopy = 0
$SearchBase = "DC=Merallis,DC=net"

# ----------------------------------------
# Checking backing up output file
# ----------------------------------------

if (Test-Path $ReportFile) {

Rename-Item -Path $ReportFile -newname $BackupFile
$BackupCopy = $BackupCopy + 1
}
Else {
$BackupCopy = 0
}


# ----------------------------------------
# Build array from list of computers in AD
# ----------------------------------------

Write-Host -NoNewline "- Gathering a list of Computers from Active Directory..."
Try
{
   $Computers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $SearchBase -Filter * -Properties Name,Description | Sort-Object 
   Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Success"
}
Catch
{
   Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Failed ($_)"
}




# -------------------------------------------------
# Use the Manage-BDE command to query each computer
# -------------------------------------------------

Write-Host "- Querying BitLocker status..."
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
   $Name = $Computer.Name
   $Description = $Computer.Description
   $BDE = Manage-BDE -ComputerName $Computer.Name -Status C:
    # -------------------------------------------------
    # Use the Get-ADComputer command to query the current attribute for each computer
    # -------------------------------------------------
    $Attribute = Get-ADComputer $Name -Properties extensionAttribute1 | select extensionAttribute1


   Write-Host -nonewline "  - $Name ..."

   If ($Attribute -notlike "*VM*" -or $Attribute -notlike "*VeraCrypt*") {
   If ($BDE -Like "*An error occurred while connecting*") {Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Unable to connect"; $Status = "Unable to connect"; Set-ADComputer -identity $Name -Replace @{"ExtensionAttribute1"=$Status}}
   ElseIf ($BDE -Like "*Protection On*") {Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Protected"; $Status = "Protected"; Set-ADComputer -identity $Name -Replace @{"ExtensionAttribute1"=$Status}}
   ElseIf ($BDE -Like "*Protection Off*") {Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $Status; $Status = "Not protected"; $UnprotectedCount = $UnprotectedCount + 1 ; Set-ADComputer -identity $Name -Replace @{"ExtensionAttribute1"=$Status}}
   ElseIf  ($BDE -Like "*The term 'manage-bde'*") {Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "error manage-bd!"; $Status = "Not protected"; $UnprotectedCount = $UnprotectedCount + 1}
   Else {Set-ADComputer -identity $Name -Replace @{"ExtensionAttribute1"="Unknown"}}
   }
   $ScanCount = $ScanCount +1
   $OutputArray += New-Object PsObject -Property @{
   'Computer name' = $Computer.Name
   'Description' = $Computer.Description
   'BitLocker status' = $Status
   }
}



# -----------------
# Generate a report
# -----------------

Write-Host -NoNewline "- Saving report..."
Try
{
   $OutputArray | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation $ReportFile
   Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Success"
}
Catch
{
   Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Failed ($_)"
}


# -----------------------------------------
# Display completion message and statistics
# -----------------------------------------

$EndDate = Get-Date -Format HH:mm:ss
$Duration = New-TimeSpan $StartDate $EndDate

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "-------------------------------------------------------------"
Write-Host "Script complete.  Start time: $StartDate, End time: $EndDate"
Write-Host "Scanned $ScanCount computers. $UnprotectedCount are unprotected!"
Write-Host "-------------------------------------------------------------"man
Write-Host ""
```

Comment: it LOOKS like your actual problem is that you are getting an object with one property that has your desired value in it. if that is the problem, use `-ExpandProperty` on your `Select-Object` call.

Comment: Also, you are attempting to output an object to the console using `Write-Host`, which stringifies the object. If you want the object, just type `$Attribute`. If you only want the value of the property, then use `$Attribute.extensionAttribute1`.

Comment: $Attribute.extensionAttribute1 did the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **filter** objects from list **based on some property** value then you can use Where-Object

i.e. Website list ( **without "default"** website **Name** )

```
$YOURLIST = Get-Website
$YOURLIST | Where-Object  { $_.Name -notlike "*Default*" }
```